# Find and Replace text in all table using mysql query

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a database with name `test` having two tables

1. `sample1(name, quote)`
2. `sample2(name, quote)`

I need a replace function or procedure that does the following

1. Find columns with String data type (Text,varchar,char,etc) in all tables within `test` database
2. Look for a value in that column and replace it with a new value

I have found an stored procedure in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822638/find-and-replace-in-entire-mysql-database#answer-4823160) but I don't understand how it works.

is there anyway to achieve this or adopt the stored procedure in the linked post for my use?

Comment: can you elaborate your questions little bit more in detail. as I can see you have two questions you want to replace something in db and how it is being related to table_schema???

Comment: with respect to replacing a specific text in entire databases. You can refer to solution provided here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822638/find-and-replace-in-entire-mysql-database

Comment: Regarding table_scheme I don't know what is this and how I can get it from phpmyadmin. can you write a sample query for it.

Comment: table_schema is nothing but your database name. If you query informaiton_schema.tables you get the details.

Comment: You searched a lot and found `table_schema'? where did you find it? How is it related to the remaining text and  the title  of your post?

Comment: If im not mistaken you are looking for a way to look for a value in all tables in a database containing a column with a string data type! and when the value found, it must be replaced with another value?! is that right?

Comment: Sorry miracle173 'table_schema' is not related with db but when I had searched I found this word.

Comment: Yes Masoud you are right.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL's [replace function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) should come handy to replace the text you need:

`update $table set column = replace(column, 'old_text', new_text') where column='old_text' and <other_conditions>;`

Now, as you talk of replace in all tables, that's something not possible in single query. Though you can create a routine to do so!
For the sample you can refer a procedure which is [finding a string in all tables of all databases](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/search-through-all-databases-tables-columns-in-mysql).

- (Though been already mentioned in comments) `table_schema` is a column name of `information_schema.tables` table which represents the database name.